# Centering a button in a vertical box

Tags: java, alignment, jbutton

Im creating a JDialog and adding components to it as such:

```
Window thisWin = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(ancestorPanel);
final JDialog progressDialog = new JDialog(ancestorPanel, "There was an error");
progressDialog.setUndecorated(true);
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
```

Next I add one JLabel, one JTextArea, one JScrollPane that contains a table, and finally a button as such:

```
label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
area.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
Box vBox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
vBox1.add(label);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
vBox1.add(area);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
vBox1.add(scroll);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
vBox1.add(button);
contentPane.add(vBox1);
progressDialog.setContentPane(contentPane);
progressDialog.pack();
progressDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(ancestorPanel);
progressDialog.setVisible(true);
```

The results is exactly as I want except for the button. The label is on top (aligned to the left), then the text area comes below it (also aligned to the left), then below that comes the table, and finally the button, but I can't seem to make the button appear in the middle of the row. Its appearing on the left. I tried using the following line but it didn't work:

```
button(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

How can I get the button to appear in the center of the last row?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the above by adding the button to a separate Box and then using Boxlayout to add both boxes to the panel as such:

```
Box vBox1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
vBox1.add(label);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
vBox1.add(area1);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
vBox1.add(scroll);
vBox1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(7));
Box vBox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
vBox2.add(button);
contentPane.add(vBox1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
contentPane.add(vBox2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```